# Google sheet switch statement to check hours and return text result

Tags: switch-statement

I have written a Google Sheet switch formula looking at times in Column E. Based on the hour of the day I am trying to return result to categorize the record and be able to aggregate the data.

The referenced cell in E2 is 10:17. The expression result is 10 in my formula. The first case is displaying as TRUE but the result I am getting is "Other". I cannot see where this is broken. It should return the result for the 1st case.

```
=SWITCH(HOUR(E2),
  AND(HOUR(E2)>=6,HOUR(E2)<11),"Morning (6-11)",
  AND(HOUR(E2)>=11,HOUR(E2)<15), "Afternoon (11-3)",
  AND(HOUR(E2)>=15,HOUR(E2)<19), "Evening (3-7)",
  "Other")
```